# Is this an attempt to hack me?

Tags: php, security, cgi-bin

So I'm hosting a web server since yesterday and I found this in my access log:

```
POST /cgi-bin/php?-d+allow_url_include%3Don+-d+safe_mode%3Doff+-d+suhosin%2Esimulation%3Don+-d+disable_functions%3D%22%22+-d+open_basedir%3Dnone+-d+auto_prepend_file%3Dphp%3A%2F%2Finput+-d+cgi%2Eforce_redirect%3D0+-d+cgi%2Eredirect_status_env%3D0+-n
```

Now I don't know what this does, but to me it seems a bit sketchy.

Comment: Is this a php related question?

Comment: Try the stack exchange sites Server Fault, Webmasters or Information Security.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like someone is trying to put the safe-mode off and trying to push and execute his PHP file on your server.

*P.S. This has nothing to do with PHP code but about your server security and you should look the used terms/commands up on Google to find out more.*

Answer (score 3):

This is an HTTP request to exploit a [vulnerability discovered by Kingcope](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-1823), where `/cgi-bin/php` is directly mapped onto the PHP executable, and the query string is used as arguments:

```
php -d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d cgi.redirect_status_env=0 -n
```

The `-d` arguments are compatible to INI entries and basically make PHP read and execute PHP code from the POST body (i. e., `auto_prepend_file=php://input`).